# How to efficeintly update the installed applications list?

Tags: android

In this question I basically don't need a written code to solve my problem, I need an efficient approach (solution, flow or logic) to solve the current problem.

In my application I have two activities ( MainActivity - InstalledAppsActivity)

As loading the installed apps list (packages names + labels + icons) takes time (Which is followed by populating a GridView):

**I preserve them in a static generic apps details list (member of InstalledAppsActivity).**

**I monitor install / uninstall apps action using AppsBroadcastReceiver** which is registered in AndroidManifest.xml

**Here's the important part**

AppsBroadcastReceiver fires a broadcast includes the package name and its status, and gets received by my InstalledAppsActivity to update the static generic installed apps details list (which updates the GridView adapter).

**So far so good, except when InstalledAppsActivity gets destroyed:**

If User presses back button, InstalledAppsActivity:unregisterReceiver takes place, and the fired broadcast with package name and status will not be received, which means the static generic list (that contains apps details and used by the GridView adapter) will not get updated.

**What is the optimal approach / flow to get my static generic apps details list to get updated, whether InstalledAppsActivity is alive or got destroyed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts):

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app specifically. For example, ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED is an implicit broadcast, since it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them know that some package on the device was replaced

There could be two approaches:

1. Start a foreground service and register `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`.
   The drawback is it will be always visible and could lead to battery drainage. It will also lead to bugging user.
2. Schedule a Job periodically using `JobScheduler`. You can then use `PackageManager.getChangedPackages`

Based on the documentation for [PackageManager.getChangedPackages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getChangedPackages(int)):

> **Returns the names of the packages that have been changed [eg. added, removed or updated] since the given sequence number**. If no packages have been changed, returns null. The sequence number starts at 0 and is reset every boot.

However based on the [BroadcastReceiver exception list](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html) you can still register to `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` to receive broadcast  when package is fully removed and perform your task accordingly

Comment: Thank you Sagar for bringing my attention to Android 8.0

Comment: So, what is the best approach to support before and after API 26, so when an app gets installed or removed I get notified immediately?

Comment: @Jack For API level lower than Android O, you can continue to use the above approach. But you need to be careful if you want to support pre Android Lollipop. JobScheduler is available starting from Android Lollipop. The alternative is JobDispatcher. You can also try to keep the broadcast receiver registered, which should work on lower versions.